# How to get mail attachment name while reading mail using mule imap inbound?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

currently i am working on one of mule use case where i need create a mule flow which reads mail from gmail account which has an attachment.

Currently i am able to retrieve the attachment data from mail, but i couldn't able to get the mail attachment name.

Can some one help me out to get the attachment name from mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you're apply MEL to is an instance of [InboundAttachmentMapContext](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.5.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/el/context/InboundAttachmentMapContext.html), which is a `Map`.

So what about using `keySet()` to get the attachment names or `entrySet()` to get entries of `(name, attachment)`?

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are instances of `javax.activation.DataHandler` - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html

SO you should be able to call .getName() or .name on each attachment using MEL. i.e `#[message.inboundAttachments.someattachment.name]`

Comment: Hi rayan, thanks for reply.in my logger i have used this mel #[message.inboundAttachments.getName()] but i am getting error Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: unable to resolve method: org.mule.el.context.InboundAttachmentMapContext.getName() [arglength=0]]

Comment: No, you need to call getName on a specific attachment, you're doing it on the full collection. You can use a <collection-splitter /> to work with them individually or use foreach etc. If you want to get a list of all the names from the attachments you can use message.inboundAttachments.getInboundAttachmentNames()

Answer (score 0):

use #[key], this will give filename inside foreach statement. 
Use #[counter] to get the file array no.